# Nashorn profiler output format

Tags: java, javascript, profiler, nashorn

Nashorn java script engine has built-in profiler which can be invoked like this:

`jjs -pcs profiled_script.js`.

This profiler produces a file named **NashornProfile.txt**. Here is an example line from this file:

```
0       dyn:getProp|getElem|getMethod:Object    764015  1
```

What is the format of this file and what is the meaning of each column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format is:

- Sequential line index
- Function name
- Total time spend inside function
- Hit count for the function

This values are tab separated. Information taken from Nashorn source, JDK 8 GA (nashorn/src/jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/linker/LinkerCallSite.java:304, ProfileDumper class).