# Get -pcs like information within a java programm

Tags: java, nashorn, scriptengine

I am currently using nashorn to run JavaScript in a java project. It is used to allow user scripting at some parts of my Java program.

I am aware of flag's like '--no-java' & '--no-syntax-extensions' to encapsulate the users JavaScript code. A few days ago I came across the option '-pcs'. It creates a Text file called 'NashornProfile.txt' in the execution directory.
(See [Nashorn profiler output format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013745/nashorn-profiler-output-format) for more info)

Is there a way to directly get the information that is written to the file or is there a similar way to get this information? I DO NOT want to read the file that is created, as I will have multiple script instances running and all of them always output to this one exact text file.

I know that the file path is hard coded into the LinkerCallSite class.
I am open to any better alternative to monitor the running script from code (especially global variables & some runtime characteristics).

I'm sorry if i overlooked something, but I am not too familiar with the scripting API.

Thanks in advance for any answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a per-process customization of the file name. -Dnashorn.profilefile= can be given. But even then all nashorn activity in the same nashorn process will result that file being updated. i.e., there is no per -script or per-engine specific profile file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The profile-file name is nice & I could get along with reading the text file by "filtering" it and decide myself what output was produced by what script. But it just feels not like a good approach. Are you aware of other options to get information/details about the running script? (Methods for Java code, as most options feel like they are build to be used when using nashorn as a pure sript executer)

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowlege, but i found that the bindings from the engine are "good enough" for monitoring the script. It's not perfect, but should work out. I would still be happy about more detailed information if there is any method. Thanks for your answer, i think it's clear that there is at least no other option to get the pcs output seperate for each running script.